# Script in for ffmpeg import-export macro that changes text lines

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, script

Was pointed here from video network for the question.

I was thinking setting up list of files from folder in excel, all with .mp4.
Around 4000 lines in total.

```
Column A - original file name  
Column B - linetext1  
Column C - linetext2  
Column D - linetext3  
Column E - export filename
```

Is it possible to setup ffmpeg or some other script (win7) to use ffmpeg to do this, so I do not have to manually do all 4000 videos:

- read excel file column A to pick video filename, starting at line 1
- use text from B column instead of textline1
- use text from C column instead of textline2
- use text from D column instead of textline3
- use text from E column as export filename

After line 1 is finished proceed to next one, and so on until the end (4000 lines).

Everything else in the ffmpeg command remains same for all videos:

```
ffmpeg -i videoin.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline1':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-130, drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline2':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-75, drawtext=enable='between(t,2.5,6.5)':fontsize=50:fontcolor=White:fontfile='ariblk.ttf':text='textline3':x=min(4*(tw\+10)-(abs(4-2*(t-2.5)))*(tw+10)-tw\,10):y=h-th-20[out]" -codec:a copy videoout.mp4
```

Comment: You should ask a complete question here, and delete the other one.

Comment: Please also read [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: It's not on-topic at VP

Comment: Here it is, full question here. I have no idea about scripting so no research in this field, but it took me few days of research to get that long sausage of command in ffmpeg if it counts.... without help from @Mulvya it would be impossible to solve it for me.